Why do we need the right-continuity of $F$ at $a$ to prove $V_F[a,c]=\lim_{b\to a^+}V_F[b,c]$ where $F$ is of finite variation?
This is a continuation of this post. The book claims the following without proof:

Proposition$\quad$ Suppose that $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is of finite variation. Suppose also that $a<c$ and $F$ is right-continuous at $a$. Then
$$
V_F[a,c]=\lim_{b\to a^+}V_F[b,c].
$$

I tried to prove it myself, but I didn't use the condition of the right-continuity of $F$ at $a$.
My attempt of the proof:

Proof$\quad$ Let $\epsilon$ be a positive number. Choose an increasing finite sequence $\{t_i\}_{i=0}^n$ of numbers that belong to $[a,c]$ and satisfy
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n|F(t_i)-F(t_{i-1})|>V_F[a,c]-\epsilon.
$$
Note that for each $b$ that satisfies $a\leq b\leq t_0$ we have
$$
V_F[a,c]-\epsilon< V_F[b,c]\leq V_F[a,c].
$$
This proves the proposition.

As you can see, it seems to me that the right-continuity of $F$ at $a$ is kind of irrelevant (although I do think the right-continuity of $V_F[b,c]$ at $a$ matters). Could someone please explain to me why do we need this assumption for this proposition? Thanks a lot in advance!

@MartinR I'm no sure if I get your point. For your second comment, ${t_i}{i=0}^n$ need not be a partition, see the first definition in this post. For your first comment, if $F$ is $0$ on $(a,c]$ and $F(a)=1$, then $V_F[a,c]=1$. But $V_F[b,c]=0$ for all $b\in(a,c]$, and so we must have $\lim{b\to a^+}V_F[b,c]=0\neq1$. Right?

@MartinR But how should I incorporate the right-continuity of $F$ at $a$ into my proof?

I have added some remarks to my answer which you might find useful (or not).

@MartinR Thank you very much! They are very helpful!

The function $F: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ defined by
$$
 F(x) = \begin{cases}
  1 & \text{ if } x \le a \\
  0 & \text{ if } x > a \\
\end{cases}
$$
has $V_F[a,c] = 1$ and $V_F[b,c] = 0$ for $a < b \le c$. This example shows that the condition “$F$ is right-continuous at $a$” can not be omitted.
Actually, if $F$ is of finite variation on $[a, c]$ then $V_F[a,c]=\lim_{b\to a^+}V_F[b,c]$ holds if and only if $F$ is right-continuous at $a$, see the remarks at the end.

So where is the error in your proof? A partition of $[a, c]$ is a finite sequence $\{t_i\}_{i=0}^n$ with
$$
  a = t_0 < t_1 < \ldots < t_n = c \, .
$$
It is true that given $\epsilon > 0$ we can find a partition with
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n|F(t_i)-F(t_{i-1})|>V_F[a,c]-\epsilon.
$$
but this does not allow any conclusion about $V_F[b,c]$ with $a < b \le c$.

If $f$ is right-continuous at $a$ then, given $\epsilon > $ we can first find a $t^* \in (a, c)$ such that
$$
  |F(t) - F(a)| < \frac 12 \epsilon
$$
for $a < t < t^*$. Then we can find a partition $\{t_i\}_{i=0}^n$ of $[a, c]$ with
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n|F(t_i)-F(t_{i-1})|>V_F[a,c]-\frac 12 \epsilon.
$$
By inserting additional points into that partition we can assume that $t_1 < t^*$. Then
$$
V_F[a,c]-\frac 12 \epsilon < \frac 12 \epsilon + \sum_{i=2}^n|F(t_i)-F(t_{i-1})| \le \frac 12 \epsilon + V_F([t_1, c])
$$
so that
$$
V_F[a,c] - \epsilon \le V_F([t_1, c]) \le V_F([b, c]) \le V_F([a, c])
$$
for $a < b \le t_1$.

Remarks: If $F$ is of finite variation on $[a, c]$ then $F$ is the difference of two nondecreasing functions. It follows that the only possible discontinuities are jump discontinuities. So, if $F$ is not right-continuous at $a$ then $L = \lim_{t \to a^+} F(t)$ exists, but $L \ne F(a)$. It is not difficult to show that
$$
V_F[a,c] \ne \lim_{b\to a^+}V_F[b,c]
$$
in this case.
